# References on Grothendieck categories

Tags: category-theory

I'm a graduate student interested in categorical algebra. I want to understand Grothendieck categories and in particular the Gabriel-Popescu theorem. See [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%E2%80%93Popescu_theorem).

I found a lot of litterature on the subject, like the Tohoku paper, the Freyd's book, the thesis of Gabriel, etc... But all those references are not adressed to a "student public". They are often too old to be pleasant to read or to specific to be approchable for beginners. I would like to find a book where all definitions are detailed, examples are given, equivalences of definitions are explained, and theorems like the Gabriel-Popescu are developped. My question is then : does there exists a pedagogic reference on Grothendieck categories? It can be a syllabus. I also speak French.

Comment: I don't think there are really many more good references than what you've listed. Something that might help is to read up on analogous theorems in areas that have had a more thorough textbook treatment. For instance, the Gabriel-Popescu theorem is more or less a special case of the classification of locally presentable categories, which have a wonderful treatment by Adamek and Rosicky.

Comment: @KevinCarlson how? does a lambda-orthogonal class end up being the same thing as a torsion-free class for a torsion theory, or is the more-or-less that a torsion-free class is an additive version of a lambda-orthogonality class?

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I guess that's not really the analogy: the Gabriel-Popescu theorem is more precisely an additive Giraud theorem.

Answer (score 3):

You may try to have a look to the chapters about "Abelian categories" and "Grothendieck categories" in Stenström's excellent book "Rings of Quotients, An Introduction to Methods of Ring Theory".

In those chapters you will find very detailed proofs for the Gabriel-Popescu Theorem and for several basic facts about Grothendieck categories (existence of products, existence of an injective cogenerator, existences of injective envelopes, ...).

Comment: Stenström's book is excellent.